# Code to navigate filepicker with watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, filepicker.io

I am testing an application that uses filepicker for file uploads:

https://www.inkfilepicker.com

I am using watir.

I have tried:

```
def upload_photos
  $b.link(:text, "Upload Photos").click
  $b.button(:text, "Choose File").click
end
```

but the code fails with:

```
`assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:text=>"Choose File", :tag_name=>"button"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException
```

Is it possible to automate filepicker uploads with watir? How?

Comment: You should give it a try and then ask a question about a specific part that you are having problems with. In general, I think Watir would be able to work (assuming I am looking at the right part of the page).

Comment: I had given it a try but watir doesn't see the filepicker upload dialog. I've updated the question with the details.

Comment: I really do not know what you are trying to automate. Where is this "Choose File" button? We need some html of your actual application or since it is using infilepicker, somewhere on the site that has the same functionality.

Comment: If you don't know filepicker, why are you trying to answer the question? "Choose File" is a button in the filepicker dialog: http://app-fusion.com/blog/filepicker-io-a-hosted-third-party-solution-for-file-uploads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
$b.button(:text, "Choose File").click
```

Has two problems (assuming your filepicker is the same as that on the inkfilepicker demo page):

1. The Choose File button is in an iframe. When it comes to frames, you need to explicitly tell Watir about them.
2. The Choose File is not a regular button; it is the button for a file field (). These are accessed from Watir using the `file_field` method. There is no support for just clicking the button. Instead, there is a `set` method that will click the button, select a file to upload and close the window.

Assuming the filepicker in your application is the same as the one on the inkfilepicker demo page, you can do the following:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

# File to upload
file = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\stuff.jpeg'

# Go to the demo page, which has a file uploader
browser.goto 'https://www.inkfilepicker.com/demos/'

# Click the button that opens the file uploader
browser.button(:class => 'zip-open-button').click

# Wait for the dialog to be displayed
browser.div(:id => 'filepicker_dialog_container').wait_until_present

# Set the file
browser.frame(:id => 'filepicker_dialog').file_field(:id => 'fileUploadInput').set(file)
```